# Decode file content

Tags: rest, file, coldfusion, decode

im working on a project which send a file to client side through api. i use the PUT method to send the file but getting 400 bad request. after checking the log, found that all my file content has been endoded. but when i download the file, its content still look ok.
may i know how to send the file and make sure the file content is decoded? Below is part of my code.

actually i do have this code before call the api, not sure whether is it bcoz of this code affect the filecontent become encoded..

```
<cffile action="write" nameconflict="overwrite" file="#filename#" output="#toString(invoiceXML)#">
<cfhttp url="#requestUrl#" method="PUT" result="res" throwonerror="yes">
    <cfhttpparam name="Authorization" type="header" value="Basic #token#">
    <cfhttpparam name="Content-Type" type="header" value="multipart/form-data">
    <cfhttpparam type="file" name="document" file="#filename#" >
</cfhttp>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

According to the [reference for cfhttpparam](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-g-h/cfhttpparam.html) the file shouldn't get URL-Encoded. Are you sure the encoding happens in the code snippet you posted?

If the reference is actually wrong and the file is getting encoded by the cfhttpparam you could try adding the `encoded` attribute:

```
<cfhttp url="#requestUrl#" method="PUT" result="res" throwonerror="yes">
    <cfhttpparam name="Authorization" type="header" value="Basic #token#">
    <cfhttpparam name="Authorization" type="header" value="Basic #token#">
    <cfhttpparam name="Content-Type" type="header" value="multipart/form-data">
    <cfhttpparam type="file" name="document" file="#filename#" encoded="no">
</cfhttp>
```

If the file contents are already encoded, you could try the [URLDecode](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-t-z/urldecode.html) function to decode it.

Comment: hi Steve, i have requested the log from the server side, and my content all encoded. i tried to add the encoded attribute, but still getting the 400 bad request..

Comment: The docs say encoded is ignored except for form fields.  If the intent is to send a file field, try adding multipart="yes". If you are trying to send xml as the request body, use type="body" instead instead of type="file".

Comment: hi @Ageax, im afraid the type cannot change to body as the requirement is, type="file". BTW, i have tried to add multipart="yes", but still the same... really dont know why the content will be encoded.

Comment: Hi @ChuanyieLim. Okay, I suggested both as I wasn't sure of the requirement. Did you also remove the multipart Content-Type header? As using both might cause problems. If there's still no change, try using Fiddler to examine the cfhttp request.  That should tell you if cfhttp is encoding the value or it's happening on the other end.

Comment: @ChuanyieLim -  Okay. I posted both options because I wasn't certain about the requirement. Make sure you removed the multipart Content-Type header, since it's handled by multipart=yes.  You might use Fiddler to inspect the cfhttp post.  That

Comment: @Ageax. Thanks for advice, i will try using Fiddler to monitor the cfhttp request.

Comment: @Ageax hi i use Fiddler to monitor the request, and the response body is still encoded.

Comment: @ChuanyieLim - I'm not able to reproduce that result using CF2018. What's your CF version? Just confirming, your current chttp call uses `multipart="yes"` and only has 2 http parameters: the authorization header and type=file, correct?

Comment: @Ageax - I'm using CF10. yes u r correct. Just now i try again, it still 400 bad request.

Comment: @ChuanyieLim - I couldn't reproduce it with CF10,0,23,302580  either. Did you verify the file contents aren't already encoded before the cfhttp call?

Comment: @Ageax - i did tried to use the below code to check the file content before the cfhttp call, and it works and is not encoded. 
<cfset myDoc=XMLParse("#filename#", false)>
<cfdump var="#myDoc#">